# Proof question in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a square matrix with $\text{Col}(A)\subseteq\text{Null}(A)$. Prove that $A^2= 0$.

I have tried using the definition of column space of A and null space of A, and matrix multiplication, but no progress.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using the definition of column space of A and null space of A, and Matrix multiplication, but no progress.

Comment: What can you say about $Ax$? What subspace does it live in?

Comment: Ax is in the null space of A, and Ax=0, where x and 0 are vectors. How do you go from there?

Comment: @Logan It is not necessarily true that $Ax = 0$. However, $Ax$ is in the column space of $A$, hence also in the null space since Col(A) is a subset of Null(A). Now, having established that $Ax$ is in the null space of $A$, what is $A(Ax)$?

Comment: @Logan As a suggestion, you should add your thought on that and effort in order to avoid downvoting and closing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that

$$A^2=A\cdot A =A\cdot [c_1\,\ldots \, c_n]=[Ac_1\,\ldots \, Ac_n]$$

where $c_1, c_2, \dots,c_n$ are the columns of $A$.

Comment: @Bungo Yes of course! I fix that, thanks.

Comment: Why is it enough to prove it for $3\times 3$ matrices?

Comment: @KentaS Yes I was referring to that particular case but it is general of course. I revise that. Thanks

Comment: I got it, Thank you so much!

Comment: I am now proved that A^2  x=0,   but I can't say A^2=0 ,  can I?

Comment: We have just proved that $A^2=0$. Isn't it clear why?

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that, for every column vector $x$ (of suitable dimension), $Ax\in\operatorname{Col}(A)$.

Comment: So, I have a new question,      A^2 x=0  does it mean A^2=0 ?

Comment: @Logan You get $A^2x=0$ for *every* $x$, so the column space of $A^2$ is $\{0\}$. The column space is the set of all column vectors of the form $Ax$.

Comment: Thank you, it completely make sense.

Answer (score 0):

A useful fact is that the range of a linear transformation is the column space of its matrix relative to the standard bases.  And that proves your result.

The reason is that if $A=(a_{ij})$, then if $\vec x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$, we have $A\vec x=x_1\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\\vdots\\a_{n1}\end{pmatrix}+\dots+x_n\begin{pmatrix}a_{1n}\\\vdots\\a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$.